# Which Content-Transfer-Encoding should I use?

Tags: forms, rfc

I am programmatically sending a `Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data` to an endpoint and my system (Ubuntu) is default on `UTF-8`.

My question is, which `Content-Transfer-Encoding` should/do I use?

Here is an example of a form part:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: ?

jacob@example.com
```

Which `Content-Transfer-Encoding` would be the safest to use?

Another example:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"; filename="message.mime"
Content-Type: message/rfc822; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: ?

From: jacob@example.com
To: jacob@example.com
Subject: testing Coreor
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0

testing Coreor
```

Comment: Can you give more details on 1)which language and library you use, 2)the type of the endpoint 3)which protocol you use ?

Comment: I am using Node.js and the endpoint shouldn't matter as I just want to stick to standards.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code to use `quoted-printable`, so I now send the below.
It works, but do you see any errors, problems or optimizations?

```
--x.ai/coreor=---14187500275550.5525101518724114
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

jacob@example.com
--x.ai/coreor=---14187500275550.5525101518724114
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"; filename="message.mime"
Content-Type: message/rfc822; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

X-Mailer: x.ai Coreor v1.test
From: =22Jacob=22 <jacob@example.com>
To: jacob@example.com
Subject: testing Coreor via Mailgun
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=3Dutf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0

testing Coreor
--x.ai/coreor=---14187500275550.5525101518724114--
```

I use [mimelib](https://github.com/andris9/mimelib) for the `quoted-printable` encoding.

Comment: Can you show us what you did to use `quoted-printable`?

Comment: Here is how I use `quoted-printable`: https://gist.github.com/webjay/66ec31e2264c62e701ac